# Finding the error with this proof that the measure of the cantor set is 0

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> Prove that the Cantor set $C$ has Lebesgue measure of zero.

This is what I did:

---

I will use $mA$ to denote the lebesgue measure of $A$.

We can express the Cantor set $C$ as: $$C=\bigcap _{n=1}^{\infty} C_n$$ where each $C_n$ is defined as the following union:

[image]

From the construction of the Cantor set, it's clear that $C_{n+1}\subseteq C_n$ and $mC_1=1$, so according to a proposition that we learned in class, $$mC=m \bigcap _{n=1}^{\infty} C_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} mC_n$$

So we have that $$mC_n=\sum_{k=0}^{3^{n-1}-1}\frac{2}{3^n}=\frac{2}{3^n}3^{n-1}=2/3$$

so $mC=\lim_{n\to\infty} mC_n=2/3$. This doesn't seam correct, but I'm not able to find the error in my proof. Where is this argument wrong?

Comment: Your $C_n$ is wrong.  We want $C_2 \subset C_1$, but that is not true for your formula.

Comment: I got that $C_n$ from here https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cantor_set#Construction_and_formula_of_the_ternary_set @GEdgar

Comment: This is not what $C_n$ means in that link.  However, if say $D_n$ is what you wrote in the black box, then we do have $C = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n$.  But the sets $D_n$ do not decrease, so the measure of the intersection is not the limit of the measures.

Comment: For instance the correct $C_2$ is $\left[0,\frac19\right] \cup \left[\frac29,\frac13\right] \cup \left[\frac23,\frac79\right] \cup \left[\frac89,1\right]\subsetneq$ your $\left[0,\frac19\right]\cup \left[\frac29,\frac13\right]\cup \left[\frac13,\frac49\right]\cup \left[\frac59,\frac43\right]\cup \left[\frac23,\frac79\right]\cup \left[\frac89,1\right].$